# REST Service waiting on a Response of asynchronous processes

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, spring-boot, jms-topic

Have a REST Service developed using Spring Boot

The API currently uses JMS to publish to a Topic & the topic has multiple subscribers.

Now, we have a process "X", which consolidates the response of these topics and pushes the response to a Queue.

Now, I would like to have the API (REST service) wait for this Queue (posted by "X") - for synchronous processing.

Would JMSReplyTo support such a case?
  http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html

Edit :

To simplify

In the example (provided in the above link) - 
   Server polls to queue & waits on it's response.

Our REST service polls to queue & has to wait on a different queue.

In other words - How does a web service wait & read from the queue - to which, it has not posted to

Comment: might be in response you send identificator of your message. and at the end of JMS processing store somewhere the result of  JMS processing.   and in your client introduce simple polling on getting results based on that identificator.   Or simply create the WebSocket (but that one is not a REST service)

Comment: Yes, for now - I am returning an UUID & asking the clients to read based on the UUID

Answer (score 0):

What we have done to fix the problem is - Not sure, that's the right way to do

1. Null Out the Default Header JMSReplyTo
2. Added our Custom Header "ReplyTo"

Even if we pass JMSReplyTo to another queue - we have observed that the response is returning to the Caller (REST API) right after the queue has processed the message.

As we Null out the JMSReplyTo - it was not returning the response.
Then, How does the response come back to REST API - the reason, we have created the custom header - ReplyTo

Each queue kept on passing the Header ReplyTo to all the further queues, where the message is passed for further processing.

If with any of the Queues, there is no further processing (which depends on some conditions on the data, client and ...) - Made the Queue post back to ReplyTo - which was the Original JMS Queue, REST API was waiting on.

This has been working consistently, However with some performance issues - considering, the message is being passed to multiple queues.

However, considering this API's main task is to make sure the data is passed to all the systems (integration point) - it is doing it's Job.

We will revisit again to see how we can change the design for better throughput.